# Slow cook pork shoulder without it falling apart

Tags: pork, slow-cooking, pork-shoulder

I have a 2Kg pork shoulder which I would like to cook in a slow cooker (first time user of a slow cooker) so it tenderizes but I also would like it to be able to be cut it in some way to serve with vegetables rather than shredding and being pulled apart. I would also like some sort of sauce with it maybe made using some cider.

How best should I cook it in the slow cooker and what would I be best adding in along with it to create a sauce/gravy which could then be served along with the pork when cooked?

Also is there anything I can do overnight, for example, which would improve the taste of both the joint and the gravy?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but requires a bit more time.  The trick is to cook it, then cool it, then heat it back up again:

1. Cook the pork shoulder
2. Drain the liquid, being careful not to poke at the meat too much
3. Remove the crock from cooker, and let it cook down
4. Place the crock in the fridge, and let chill overnight

The next day you can slice the meat, then pour the juices back over it to warm it back up.  (or reduce the juices to make a sauce)